# Intersection point of a perpendicular line from a point and a curve

Tags: python, line, point, curve

I need to get the coordinates of the intersection `point B` of a perpendicular line through `point A` and a `curve` (the red line). Now I know the `point A` coordinates `(x1,y1)`, the curve function is a cubic polynomial `y = ax^3+bx^2+c^x`, how do I calculate the x and y coordinates of `point B` use `Python`? Note that the curve is the fitting curve of these blue points.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a math question. Do you have equation of line `AB`? Or Do you know any other point on `AB` besides `A`?

Comment: Use a math approach. See [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264702/shortest-distance-from-point-to-curve) and such other refs.

Comment: The only information is the point A coordinates and the curve function, the math approach helps a lot!